# Form Click() with a Token

Tags: forms, powershell, click, token

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Open a site and click "I accept" button to accept terms. (**works**)
2. Above redirects me to a login page where I enter username and password. (**works**)
3. Click "Log in". (**fails**, but I get no errors)

I have enabled Protected Mode, although I am unable to run scripts as Sys Admin. One other point is that, this site appears to post a token when clicking "Log in" button. Any idea why the solution does not work?

HTML:

```html
<form id="mainform" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="/URL/" onsubmit="submitHandler(); return true;">
<table class="loginTable">

...

<tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="colSpanRow" id="loginSubmitTd">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" tabindex="4" id="loginSubmit" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("url")

Start-Sleep -s 2

$link = @($ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName('A')) |
        Where-Object {$_.InnerText -eq 'I accept'}
$link.Click()

Start-Sleep -s 5

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('username').Value = "username"
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('password').Value = "pw"

$submitButton = @($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('input')) |
                Where-Object {$_.Value -eq 'Log in'}
Write-Host $submitButton.id
$submitButton.Click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you avoid using `IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName` and use the `getElementsByTagName` function.

In your code this would then be

```
$submitButton = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input')) | Where-Object {$_.value -eq 'Log in'}
```

or maybe even better:

```
$submitButton = $ie.Document.getElementById('loginSubmit')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not fix the issue. I also noticed that when I manually click "Log in", it sometimes works and sometimes doesnt. Its as if the data gets lost at times. That is, if I manually write the login details I am able to login.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this started working after changing IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName to getElementById AND changing " " to ' '.

Comment: Ah, great. Could have been caching why it didn't work straight away. I was just going to ask you what is going on in your `submitHandler()` function because that code you did not show, but then I would have adviced you to post a new question.. No need for that now luckily!